# how to push the results that come from several consecutive calls

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, push

I'm trying to get all response, and push that in an array. After I get all response I want to show tham in view

For that I'm developing this function:

For each value I'm making different call:

"listaCodiciPanFlotta": [
92994906,
92994940,
92994907,
92994941,
92994908,
92994910
]

```
       dettaglioPan.forEach(x => {
                   let codicePans = x.listaCodiciPanFlotta;
                       if (codicePans.length > 0) {
                           codicePans.forEach(value => {
                           this.getCodicePanList(value);})
                                }
                            })



getCodicePanList(value) {
    let codicePanList = [];
    this.dettaglioPanService.findDettaglioCodicePanList('pan', 'dettaglioPan',
        [
            { name: 'codicePan', value: value },
        ])
        .subscribe(dettaglioCodicePan => {
            this.listaCodiciPanFlottaStatus = true;
            codicePanList.push(dettaglioCodicePan)
            this.dettaglioCodicePanData = codicePanList;
        })
}
```

The result here is: only the last response is pushed. I want to have the array with all the answers that have been received according to the list codes. So the list has 6 codes, I want there to be 6 different answers in the array.

Thank your for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you are creating new array and pushing just one item to it. Instead you should have created array once, and push all items to it. Like this:

```
this.dettaglioCodicePanData = [];
dettaglioPan.forEach(x => {
                       let codicePans = x.listaCodiciPanFlotta;
                           if (codicePans.length > 0) {
                               codicePans.forEach(value => {
                               this.getCodicePanList(value);})
                                    }
                                })
    
    
    
    getCodicePanList(value) {
        let codicePanList = [];
        this.dettaglioPanService.findDettaglioCodicePanList('pan', 'dettaglioPan',
            [
                { name: 'codicePan', value: value },
            ])
            .subscribe(dettaglioCodicePan => {
                this.listaCodiciPanFlottaStatus = true;
                this.dettaglioCodicePanData.push(dettaglioCodicePan);
            })
    }
```

here instead of assigning arrays with one element to dettaglioCodicePanData, you would just push all elements to it directly